# adding two Pandas columns, getting TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, int found

Tags: python, pandas

adding two Pandas columns, getting

```
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, int found
```

I have a pandas dataframe, X:

x.dtypes

```
ID name                                               object
STUDY (Living allowance)                              object
STUDY (Non-living allowance)                          object
Age Pension                                           object
```

---

I want to add a totals column:

```
x['total'] = x['STUDY (Living allowance)']+x['STUDY (Non-living allowance)']
```

i get the following error:

```
TypeErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-110-282f9bf5493b> in <module>()
----> 1 x['total'] = x['STUDY (Living allowance)']+x['STUDY (Non-living allowance)']
C:\Users\~\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops.pyc in wrapper(left, right, name, na_op)
    639                     rvalues = algos.take_1d(rvalues, ridx)
    640 
--> 641             arr = na_op(lvalues, rvalues)
    642 
    643             return left._constructor(wrap_results(arr), index=index,

C:\Users\~\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops.pyc in na_op(x, y)
    586                 result = np.empty(x.size, dtype=dtype)
    587                 mask = notnull(x) & notnull(y)
--> 588                 result[mask] = op(x[mask], _values_from_object(y[mask]))
    589             elif isinstance(x, np.ndarray):
    590                 result = np.empty(len(x), dtype=x.dtype)

TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, int found
```

i notice that i can add two of the same column with no errors

```
x['total'] = x['STUDY (Living allowance)']+x['STUDY (Living allowance)']
```

Comment: You cannot add objects of two different types: `STUDY (Living allowance) object` and `STUDY (Non-living allowance) object` are of different types.

Comment: they are both type: OBJECT. you mean i cant add different objects?

Comment: `object` is the most general dtype that pandas will report. The data itself could be of different/multiple different types. Could you provide a sample of the data?

Comment: Thanks you are right, some non numeric characters had turned the column into a string type.